# How to affect only letters, not punctuation in Caesar Cipher code

Tags: ruby, caesar-cipher

I am trying to write a Caesar Cipher in Ruby and I hit a snag when trying to change only the letters to a numerical values and not the punctuation marks.

Here is my script so far:

```
def caesar_cipher(phrase, key)
    array = phrase.split("")        
    number = array.map {|n| n.upcase.ord - (64-key)}
    puts number
end

puts "Script running"
caesar_cipher("Hey what's up", 1)
```

I tried to use `select` but I couldn't figure out how to select only the punctuation marks or only the letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) to match only the characters that you want to replace. In this case it's the letters of the alphabet, so you'll use the regular expression `/[a-z]/i`.

You can pass a block to `gsub` which will be called for each match in the string, and the return value of the block will be used as the replacement. For example:

```
"Hello, world!".gsub(/[a-z]/i) {|chr| (chr.ord + 1).chr }
# => Ifmmp, xpsme!"
```

Here's a version of your Caesar cipher method that works pretty well:

```
BASE_ORD = 'A'.ord

def caesar_cipher(phrase, key)
  phrase.gsub(/[a-z]/i) do |letter|
    orig_pos = letter.upcase.ord - BASE_ORD
    new_pos = (orig_pos + key) % 26
    (new_pos + BASE_ORD).chr
  end
end

caesar_cipher("Hey, what's up?", 1) # => "IFZ, XIBU'T VQ?"
```

#### Edit:

`%` is the [modulo operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Numeric.html#method-i-25). Here it's used to make `new_pos` "wrap around" to the beginning of the alphabet if it's greater than 25.

For example, suppose `letter` is `"Y"` and `key` is 5. The position of "Y" in the alphabet is 24 (assuming "A" is 0), so `orig_pos + key` will be 29, which is past the end of the alphabet.

One solution would be this:

```
new_pos = orig_pos + key

if new_pos > 25
  new_pos = new_pos - 26
end
```

This would make `new_pos` 3, which corresponds to the letter "D," the correct result. We can get the same result more efficiently, however, by taking "29 [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 26"—expressed in Ruby (and many other languages) as `29 % 26`—which returns the remainder of the operation 29 ÷ 26. (because there are 26 letters in the alphabet). `29 % 26` is 3, the same result as above.

In addition to constraining a number to a certain range, as we do here, the modulo operator is also often used to test whether a number is divisible by another number. For example, you can check if `n` is divisible by 3 by testing `n % 3 == 0`.

Comment: Thank You! the gsub is definitely working on leaving out the punctuation marks! There are a few things in your solution that I don't understand, would you mind explaining? I understand all of it until % 26, what does this do? Also when I run your script, I get an array instead of the string you are showing "IFZ, XIBU'T VQ?"

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain the modulo (`%`) operator. `gsub` always returns a string, so I'm not sure why you're getting an array.